# Naive Bayes classifier bases decision only on a-priori probabilities

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I'm trying to classify tweets according to their sentiment into three categories (Buy, Hold, Sell). I'm using R and the package e1071.

I have two data frames: one trainingset and one set of new tweets which sentiment need to be predicted.

trainingset dataframe:

```
   +--------------------------------------------------+

   **text | sentiment**

   *this stock is a good buy* | Buy

   *markets crash in tokyo* | Sell

   *everybody excited about new products* | Hold

   +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to train the model using the tweet text  `trainingset[,2]` and the sentiment category `trainingset[,4]`.

```
classifier<-naiveBayes(trainingset[,2],as.factor(trainingset[,4]), laplace=1)
```

Looking into the elements of classifier with

`classifier$tables$x`

I find that the conditional probabilities are calculated..There are different probabilities for every tweet concerning Buy,Hold and Sell.So far so good.

However when I predict the training set with:

`predict(classifier, trainingset[,2], type="raw")`

I get a classification which is based **only** on the a-priori probabilities, which means every tweet is classified as Hold (because "Hold" had the largest share among the sentiment). So every tweet has the same probabilities for Buy, Hold, and Sell:

```
      +--------------------------------------------------+

      **Id | Buy | Hold | Sell**

      1  |0.25 | 0.5  | 0.25

      2  |0.25 | 0.5  | 0.25

      3  |0.25 | 0.5  | 0.25

     ..  |..... | ....  | ...

      N  |0.25 | 0.5  | 0.25

     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? 
Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you trained the model using **whole sentences** as inputs, while it seems that you want to use **words** as your input features.

> Usage:
>
> ```
> ## S3 method for class 'formula'
> naiveBayes(formula, data, laplace = 0, ..., subset, na.action = na.pass)
> ## Default S3 method:
> naiveBayes(x, y, laplace = 0, ...)
>
>
> ## S3 method for class 'naiveBayes'
> predict(object, newdata,
>   type = c("class", "raw"), threshold = 0.001, ...)
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
>   x: A numeric matrix, or a data frame of categorical and/or
>      numeric variables.
>
>   y: Class vector.
> ```

In particular, if you train `naiveBayes` this way:

```
x <- c("john likes cake", "marry likes cats and john")
y <- as.factor(c("good", "bad")) 
bayes<-naiveBayes( x,y )
```

you get a classifier able to recognize just these two sentences:

```
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors

Call:
naiveBayes.default(x = x,y = y)

A-priori probabilities:
y
 bad good 
 0.5  0.5 

Conditional probabilities:
            x
      x
y      john likes cake marry likes cats and john
  bad                0                         1
  good               1                         0
```

to achieve a **word level** classifier you need to run it with words as inputs

```
x <-             c("john","likes","cake","marry","likes","cats","and","john")
y <- as.factors( c("good","good", "good","bad",  "bad",  "bad", "bad","bad") )
bayes<-naiveBayes( x,y )
```

you get

```
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors

Call:
naiveBayes.default(x = x,y = y)

A-priori probabilities:
y
 bad good 
 0.625 0.375 

Conditional probabilities:
      x
y            and      cake      cats      john     likes     marry
  bad  0.2000000 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
  good 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

In general `R` is not well suited for processing NLP data, `python` (or at least `Java`) would be much better choice.

To convert a sentence to the words, you can use the `strsplit` function

```
unlist(strsplit("john likes cake"," "))
[1] "john"  "likes" "cake"
```

Comment: Re: converting the tweets to words, this can also be done quite easily in R with the `tm` text mining package (cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/) It has many tools to simplify the process such as removing stop words (e.g, "the", "it"), capitalization, etc. The package has a nice [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) worth exploring.